# What are the drawbacks of choosing nodejs over asp.net or java for any products?

Tags: java, asp.net, node.js

There are lots of programming languages available in the market then how do we decide what programming language we should use for our products?

1. What are the key factors we should consider before using any programming language?
2. What are the capabilities of language we should check for long term?

Please share your views

Comment: That's too broad. There are way more points of consideration when choosing language and technology than we can express in the form of an answer. If you at least describe your product, then there may be a "winner" technology, but as it stands - there's not and there can't be.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start with your 2nd Question - "Long Term", well dont assume the Programming Language alone will help you for the long term. Of course Language will have its impact but take a look at the Architecture when you want to think about Long Term.

Both Java and JavaScript are very capable languages, you must identify your Software Requirement and decide on what language is the best for you.

e.g. If its a Quick project (such as an Adacemic assignment) making use of Node will get you off the ground faster.

Pay attention to the Quality Attributes and think what is the best choice for you...
Performance: You'll find various benchmarks stating Node may not be the best choice if you wants to do heavy lifting.

In General for Factors for the choice of Language go through https://www.uniassignment.com/essay-samples/information-technology/the-factors-influencing-choice-of-programming-language-information-technology-essay.php

Comment: Thank you Crdesilva for answering :-)